# Powershell replace command not removing newline

Tags: powershell, replace

I have text that prints out like this:

```
mdbAppText_Arr: [0]: The  cover is open. {goes to next line here}
Please close the cover. and [1] Backprinter cover open 
46
```

I tried getting rid of the newline after open., and it's still there.  Any idea of a better way or fix for what I'm doing?  I need to get rid of the newline because it's going to a csv file, and messing up formatting (going to newline there).

This is my code:

```
$mdbAppText_Arr = $mdbAppText.Split("|")                        
$mdbAppText_Arr[0].replace("`r",";").replace("`n",";").replace("`t",";").replace("&",";") 
#replace newline/carriage return/tab with semicolon
if($alarmIdDef -eq "12-7")
{
     Write-Host "mdbAppText_Arr: [0]: $($mdbAppText_Arr[0]) and [1] $($mdbAppText_Arr[1]) "
     [byte] $mdbAppText_Arr[0][31]
}
```

I've been looking at:

[replace](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-replace/)

[replace](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/5fqjxu/replacen_leaves_a_hidden_new_line_in_a_strings/) - this one has a link reference to lookup in the asci table, but it's unclear to me what column the byte equivalent is in the table/link.

I'm using PowerShell 5.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-replace` is a *regex* operator, so you need to supply a valid regular expression pattern as the right-hand side operand.

You can replace most newline sequences with a pattern describing a substring consisting of:

- an optional carriage return (`\r?` in regex), followed by
- a (non-optional) newline character (`\n` in regex):

```
$mdbAppText_Arr = $mdbAppText_Arr -replace '\r?\n'
```

Comment: Expanded  to encompass removal of ampersands / tabs (as per OP initial sequence '-replace "&|\t|\r?\n",';''

Comment: @SagePourpre Looks like an answer waiting to be written :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works great!  :)